# val studentList = mutableListOf<Student>() , why use <student> and all bold letter i don't understand

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

// Using simple class class Student(val name: String, val rollNumber: Int, val percentageMarks: Double) {

fun printValues(){ println("Name: $name, Roll Number: $rollNumber, Percentage: $percentageMarks") } }

fun main() { val studentList = mutableListOf() studentList.add(Student("Cristina", 1290, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Mark", 1291, 88.25)) studentList.add(Student("Lea", 1292, 71.0)) studentList.add(Student("Jack", 1293, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Anies", 1294, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Danielle", 1295, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Sandra", 1296, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Katina", 1297, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Edgar", 1298, 78.5)) studentList.add(Student("Felix", 1299, 78.5))

for (i in studentList){ i.printValues() } }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you're asking is unclear, could you please add a precise question? Also, please format your code, you can put a line with triple backticks before and after your code snippet to format is as code.

Comment: I tried to guess your question and give it a go. If this is what you were asking, please still clarify your question for future readers. Also, what is your question about bold letters? There are no bold letters here. Did you mean capital letters?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking why you need to specify `<Student>` in the call to `mutableListOf()`. If not, please clarify your question.

Most of the time, Kotlin [infers the types](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#type-inference) of your variables so you don't have to worry about writing them. For instance, you can write `val i = 42` instead of `val i: Int = 42` because Kotlin can guess that the type of the expression on the right is `Int`. This is possible only when Kotlin can tell with certainty what the type of the expression is (42 is an integer literal, so it's easy for the compiler).

Now the function `mutableListOf()` is a [generic function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-functions), meaning it has a type parameter. The type of its return value depends on that type parameter. The expression `mutableListOf(42)` is OK for the compiler, because it can infer that the type parameter of `mutableListOf` must be `Int` because 42 is an `Int`. However, `mutableListOf()` without arguments provides no information about the type of the elements in the list, so the compiler doesn't know and cannot infer the type.

There are 2 solutions for this:

1. you can explicitly specify the type parameter of `mutableListOf` by writing `mutableListOf<Student>()`. This lets the compiler know the type of the result of `mutableListOf` must be `List<Student>`. In turn, this means it can infer the type of your variable `studentList`
2. you could also specify the type of the variable directly, and in this case the compiler will guess the other way around (it will know that `mutableListOf`'s type parameter must be `Student` in order to comply with the type of the variable):

```kotlin
val studentList = mutableListOf() // doesn't compile, cannot infer the type
val studentList = mutableListOf<Student>() // solution 1
val sutdentList: List<Student> = mutableListOf() // solution 2
```